# participantQuitInTurnWithOutcome:nextParticipants:turnTimeout:matchData:completionHandler: in Swift - xcode compile error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, gamekit

When I attempt to use

**participantQuitInTurnWithOutcome:nextParticipants:turnTimeout:matchData:completionHandler:**

in Swift (found in GameKit), I get the following Xcode compile error...

```
 "Extra argument 'turnTimeout' in call".
```

If I take out the turnTimeout: argument, Xcode complains with,

```
 "Missing argument for parameter 'turnTimeout' in call".
```

Has anyone else encountered this and is there any way to solve? I obviously can't satisfy each requirement.

```
func turnBasedMatchmakerViewController(viewController: GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController!, playerQuitForMatch match: GKTurnBasedMatch!) {


    var nextParts:Array<GKTurnBasedParticipant> = []
    for participant in match.participants {
        if (participant.matchOutcome == GKTurnBasedMatchOutcome.None) {
             nextParts.append(participant as GKTurnBasedParticipant)
        }
    }

    match.participantQuitInTurnWithOutcome(matchOutcome: GKTurnBasedMatchOutcome.Quit, nextParticipants: nextParts, turnTimeout: nil, matchData: self.currentMatch, completionHandler: nil)

}
```

Comment: The Swift compiler messages can be quite misleading. The first thing you should do is to check if all arguments have the correct type. (And without seeing your actual code probably nobody can help.)

Answer (score 0):

MartinR got me thinking in the right direction. It turned out that I was passing the match as the matchData argument. They are obviously two different objects.

MartinR - please post your suggestion as an answer and I will accept.